# Django filtering on DateTimeField extremely slow

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

#### Environment

- AWS RDS t3.micro (2 vCPUs, 1GiB RAM)
- PostgreSQL 11.10

I have more than **15 million** records of `Note`, the model of which is like:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    ...
    post_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

FYI, `Note` has 35+ fields, some of which are `ManyToManyField` and `ForeignKey` fields.

#### Problem

```
start_time = time.time()                         
queryset = Note.objects.filter(       
    # post_date__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=6),           
    post_date__year=2021,                           
    post_date__month__gt=7,                         
)[:100]                                          
tmp = list(queryset)                             
print("Time elapsed: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

The code above takes just 0.68 seconds, but if I uncomment `# post_date__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=6),` the time increases to 55.53 seconds.

To mitigate this issue I'm considering converting the `DateTimeField` to `PositiveIntegerField` for storing timestamp values instead. Before taking that step, is there anything else that I can try? Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the `post_date` column indexed?  That ought to help for the commented out query.  Perhaps not so much for the year / month queries.  Consider running Postgresql's [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/using-explain.html) on the SQL that Django generates.

Comment: You are relying on `post_date=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=6)` to filter for a specific datetime? That will not really work properly, as that query means you are looking for a datetime matching upto at least a second (a microsecond for PostgreSQL), i.e. some seconds off won't match. Also you might want to add an index to the field if you filter much on it.

Comment: When it takes longer, do you query for all three conditions or only the first one?

Comment: @snakecharmerb No it's not indexed, and I'll try it out.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that's just for demonstration purpose, normally I would use `post_date__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(days=6)` which is also very slow. I'll try indexing on `post_date` and see how it works!

Comment: @hendrikschneider in both cases (all three or only the first one) it is similarly slow.

Comment: have you installed django debug toolbar? Then you can see what which queries are being executed and what takes the most time

Comment: I am not understanding the rationale behind the filter in the first place?  Filter conditions are `AND`ed, so you are looking for a specific date 6 days ago that by default is going to meet the other conditions anyway. So why the three conditions? Also are you looking for a date or a point in time?

Comment: @hendrikschneider Both django debug toolbar and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` didn't help for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The filter itself doen't really mean anything, I just wanted to demonstrate that the `__gt` filter on `DateTimeField` takes forever, whereas `__month__gt` does not.

Comment: @shinhong wondering what you ended up doing.

Comment: @zerohedge AFAIR, indexing didn't work out well and I switched to PositiveIntegerField and epoch timestamp. I still have no idea what was going on here. Are you having the same issue?